# Django comments framework issues

Tags: django, django-templates, django-comments

Im trying to implement commenting on my site using the comments framework. I've followed the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/example/

My template looks like:

```
{% extends "pbase.html" %}
{% load comments %}
{% block bcontent %}

    <div class="main">
        <a href="{{ backurl }}">&lt;&lt; back</a>
        <!-- Image -->
        <ul>
            {% if image.title %}
                <div class="title">{{ image.title }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <ul>
                <img border="0" alt="" src="{{ media_url }}{{ image.image.name }}" width="900" />
            </ul>
        </ul>
        {% load comments %}
        {% get_comment_count for photo.image object_pk as comment_count %}
        <p>{{ comment_count }} comments have been posted.</p>
        {% render_comment_list for photo.image object_pk %}
        {% render_comment_form for photo.image object_pk %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

On my page the number of comments is show but not the comments themselves or the form. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you created the `comments/list.html` template?

Comment: What happens if you do just `{% load comments %} {% render_comment_list for photo.image %}`?

Comment: From the documentation i understand that there is a default list.html template? I wanted to get it working with that before customising.
@agf i get the error "Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'" thanks

Comment: Thankyou, i knew i was missing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`photo.image` should be just `image`. I know `image` is correct because you use it elsewhere in the template, and if it were wrong, you'd notice.